# giraph/ hadoop reading manifest file

Tags: hadoop, giraph

I am trying to run RandomWalkWith Restart example https://github.com/apache/giraph/blob/release-1.0/giraph-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/giraph/examples/RandomWalkWithRestartVertex.java
My Input is data is 
12  34  56
34  78
56  34  78
78  34

and I am running

```
hadoop jar giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar   GiraphRunner -Dgiraph.zkList=<host>:port -libjars giraph-examples-1.1.0-for-hadoop-2.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
 org.apache.giraph.examples.RandomWalkWithRestartComputation
 -mc org.apache.giraph.examples.RandomWalkVertexMasterCompute 
-wc org.apache.giraph.examples.RandomWalkWorkerContext
-vof org.apache.giraph.examples.VertexWithDoubleValueDoubleEdgeTextOutputFormat 
-vif org.apache.giraph.examples.LongDoubleDoubleTextInputFormat 
-vip giraph_algorithms/personalized_pr/input/graph.txt
-op giraph_algorithms/personalized_pr/out1 -w 1
```

But I am getting this error.. :-/

```
Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: run: Caught an unrecoverable exception
 For input string: "PK�uE    META-INF/��PKPK�uEMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MF�M��LK-.�" at 
org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphMapper.run(GraphMapper.java:101) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162) Caused by:  
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "PK�uE    META-INF/��PKPK�uEMETA-
INF/MANIFEST.MF�M��LK-.�" at 
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) at  
java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441) at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483) at 
org.apache.giraph.examples.RandomWalkWorkerContext.initializeSources(
RandomWalkWorkerContext.java:131) at org.apache.giraph.examples.RandomWalkWorkerContext.
setStaticVars(RandomWalkWorkerContext.java:160) at 
org.apache.giraph.examples.RandomWalkWorkerContext
.preApplication(RandomWalkWorkerContext.java:146) at 
 org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager.workerContextPreApp(
GraphTaskManager.java:815) at 
 org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager.
prepareGraphStateAndWorkerContext(GraphTaskManager.java:451) at 
org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphTaskManager.execute(GraphTaskManager.java:266) at 
org.apache.giraph.graph.GraphMapper.run(GraphMapper.java:91) ... 7 more
```

Why is it reading manifest file.. When I specifically saying it to read a file and not even a directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you passed the `libjar` argument as the vertex class file.

Like the other arguments, you need to say: `-D libjars=your_jar.jar`.